# Can't send cookie with axios

Tags: node.js, reactjs, cookies, axios

I have a nodejs backend and a react frontend. In the backend, I set a cookie like this:

```
res.cookie('cook', token, { httpOnly: true });
```

I'm using cookie-parser ofc, it's all set (`app.use(cookieParser());`);

In my react app, I'm using axios like this:

```
axios({
  method: 'get',
  url: 'MY_URL',
  withCredentials: true
});
```

When I use chrome devtools network response, I see the response of the cookie, so the cookie is set by the nodejs server? But the cookies does not pop up in the 'applications" tab in chrome devtools and subsequents requests with axios are not including the cookie.

What am I overseeing?

Comment: please show the server response.

Comment: Also: are frontend and backend on the same domain/subdomain?

Comment: frontend is localhost:8001, backend is localhost:5000. Cors policy is set server-side. What server response do you mean?

Comment: The set cookie response

Comment: Also: double check that there are not any errors in the dev tools and server side.